# select a dynamic range in Excel from starting cell and look for Matching values in other rows

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, vba

I have a spreadsheet where if the selected cell is B2 then excel would select the  range A2:E2 but if the value of B3 is the same as B2 then the range would be A2:E3. I need this to also continue if there are say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,etc rows with the same value in B2.

Once it has carried out the rest of the macro I would like it to then return to the end of the previous selected range and move one row down and repeat the process until it meets an empty cell in column D.
[example of spreadsHeet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePkkO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your code, create a variable to save the address of the [`ActiveCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activecell-property-excel):

```
Dim lastCell As String
lastCell = ActiveCell.Address
```

At the end of your code, select that cell, except +1 row using [`Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel):

```
Range(lastCell).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Then you can check whether the new active cell is blank, and take action as needed:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    'cell is empty
    Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down another cell
    '...do something here...
Else
    'cell is not empty
    '...do something here...
End If
```

Comment: FYI - `Range(ActiveCell.Address)` can be simplified to `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Yeah, lots of code can be simplified but the shorter I make it, the more people seem to complain...   :-)

Here is the same code: 
`Dim l, r: l = ActiveCell: r = Range(l).Offset(1, 0): r.Select: If r='' Then Range(r).Offset(1, 0).Select`

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm struggling getting it to select the Range of its findings Columns A:Q.

Comment: I have edited the wording of my question based around the example image I've added. Sorry for the confusion I hope it makes it clearer.